# jQuery URL Get error on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Can anyone point out why my JavaScript function is falling into the error function rather than the success function?  Firefox on Ubuntu

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        console.log( "Start" );
        $.ajax({ type: "GET", dataType: "html", url: "http://slashdot.org",
        error: function(request, status) {
            console.log("Error");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Sucess");
        }
        });
            console.log( "End" );
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to one of the most common Javascript issues.  Read this: [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: change your url for one that it's in the same domain as the server serving your page.

Comment: @PbxMan I'm sure that doesn't help. They seem to need data from a separate domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of [same-origin security restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), you cannot issue ajax calls to domains other than the domain of your current web page.

Possible work-arounds depending upon what your actual problem is:

1. Build a server proxy on your domain that will fetch the web page from the other site for you so you can send the request to your own domain.
2. Use an iframe to display the content from another domain.

Answer (score 1):

It is very common issue with Cross Domain Policy. If you are using jQuery Ajax then you can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to do cross domain query. Document at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
 $.ajax({ type: "GET", dataType: "json", url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/stackoverflow/media/recent?client_id=0324ff3396ef4ab49697505678e734f5&callback=?",
      error: function(request, status) {
           console.log(request, status);
      },
      success: function(data) {
           console.log(data);
      }
 });
```